# UIButton and UITextField unclickable due to UIScrollView placement?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I've began iOS development recently and have created a basic layout using Interface Builder.  However, I've noticed that my `UIScrollView` is causing my `UITextField` and `UIButton` to be unclickable (up to a certain point).

Here is a screenshot.  Everything above the red line is clickable and responds to touch events, but everything below is/does not.

[image: Red line screenshot indicating clickability/response to touch events]

I decided to move my `UIScrollView` down a few pixels, and noticed this "red line" moved down as well.  After shrinking the height of the `UIScrollView` from 589px to 550px, I am now able to click anywhere on the button/in the text field (since the theoretical "red line" is now just below the button).  Here is that screenshot:

[image: After moving the UIScrollView down, I can now click the button/text field]

So, my question is, why was the `UIScrollView` doing this to my `UITextField` and `UIButton`?  It seems as though it was overlapping the text field and button somehow, despite it appearing to be physically below them.  Is there any way to avoid this "overlap" without having to sacrifice those 39 pixels I gave up to prevent the "overlap"?

Comment: write this code in viewDidLoad [self.view sendSubviewToBack:scrolView];, Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, this actually did fix the problem!  However, I'm still curious as to why this overlap was occurring.  Also, when I begin adding things to the `UIScrollView`, will the items on the very top be unclickable?

Comment: No, items you added on UIScrollView at top will also be clickable, you can try with adding some items from xib directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in `viewDidLoad` function

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:scrolView];
```

Hope this helps you..